# JSON to XML Schemas in BizTalk 2013R2

Tags: json, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

Working on developing a BizTalk 2013R2 solution that calls a REST API, returns data, transforms the data against a map and spits out a .csv on the other side

There's a major hurdle I can't get around currently that I'd like to overcome;

- The API call returns the extract in JSON format. Whilst I can easily build a JSON decoding receive pipeline, the elements within the JSON extract are numerical, so I can't build an appropriate schema (example of element below) - which gives

> Name cannot begin with the 'X' character, hexadecimal value

```
"412345": [
    {
        "LineID": 123456,
        "LineDescription": "This is a description",
        "Year": 2020,
        "Month": 1,
    },
    ...
```

Is there any way I can treat this element before it's picked up without any major code (e.g. can the element be automatically appended with a letter?)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to have another pipeline component that runs in the Decode section of the pipeline that would have to replace the first part of the message.

If the number changes for each message, rather than adding a letter to it you probably want to make it a value, rather than a name.

e.g.

```
Code: "412345",
Lines: [{
        "LineID": 123456,
        "LineDescription": "This is a description",
        "Year": 2020,
        "Month": 1,
    },
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, the more I think about this, the more I've realised that the API's return is not suitably structured for what we need from it. It may just be easier to code this solution outside of BizTalk.

Comment: @mrc85 Can't you ask the owner of the API to change the structure of the JSON?  As even for JSON, that is a strange way of having data.

Comment: You'd think wouldn't you? Sadly not, incredibly difficult supplier to work with. I've handed the task over to our application development team now anyway, they can build a solution within C# and an endpoint. Cheers though